# sas issue with retain to replace missing data

Tags: sas

The following inherited simplified code is meant to replace missing values of a column with the values of not missing entries in a group:

```
DATA WORK.TOYDATA;
   INPUT Category $ PRICE;
   DATALINES;
Cat1 2
Cat1 .
Cat1 .
Cat2 .
Cat2 3
Cat2 .
;

DATA WORK.OUTTOYDATA;
SET WORK.TOYDATA;
   BY Category ;
   RETAIN _PRICE;
   IF FIRST.Category THEN _PRICE=PRICE;
   IF NOT MISSING(PRICE) THEN _PRICE=PRICE;
 ELSE PRICE=_PRICE;
 DROP _PRICE;
RUN;
```

Unfortunately, this will not work if the first entry in a group is missing. How could this be fixed?

Comment: Can a category be associated with several different prices or just one ?

Comment: @Vincent - I think it can and this is another issue I see ...

Comment: If so, you need a rule to decide which value you want to use for imputation (e.g the maximal/minimal value, the first value you encounter, a random existing value, etc.)

Comment: Jetzler answer will use the maximum value, whereas Keith's will use the average in each category.

Comment: @vincent - thanks. Just curious what makes Jetzler's answer explicitly using the max and not the minimum?

Comment: I guess he assumed that one category could only have one price. If so, sorting with `DESCENDING` is ok because you get all the missing values at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SAS works row by row through the dataset there is no value to replace if the first value is missing.
You could sort the data by Category and Price DESCENDING to circumvent this.

```
proc sort data= WORK.TOYDATA; by Category DESCENDING PRICE; run;
```

Or if there is only one NON-missing value by category you could use a sql join e.g.

```
proc sql;
create table WORK.OUTTOYDATA as
    select a.Category, coalesce(a.PRICE, b.PRICE) as PRICE
        from WORK.TOYDATA a
            left join   (select distinct Category, PRICE
                            from WORK.TOYDATA 
                                where PRICE ne .
                                ) b
            on a.Category eq b.Category
        ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jetzler pointed out, the easiest way is just to sort the data.  However, if you have multiple columns with missing values then you'd need to do multiple sorts, which isn't efficient.

Another option from doing a join is `proc stdize` which can be used to replace missing values with a simple measure (mean, median, sum etc).  The default method will suffice in your example, you just need to add the `reponly` option which only replaces missing values and does not standardize the data.

```
DATA WORK.TOYDATA;
   INPUT Category $ PRICE;
   DATALINES;
Cat1 2
Cat1 .
Cat1 .
Cat2 .
Cat2 3
Cat2 .
;
run;

proc stdize data=TOYDATA out=want reponly;
by category;
var price;
run;
```